# python convert unknown character to ascii

Tags: python, character-encoding

In a text file I'm processing, I have characters like ����. Not sure what they are.

I'm wondering how to remove/convert these characters.

I have tried to convert it into ascii by using .encode(‘ascii’,'ignore’). python told me char is not whithin 0,128

I have also tried unicodedata, unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('ascii','ignore'), with the same error

Anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: `od -x` reports `bfef efbd bdbf bfef efbd bdbf`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always take a Unicode string an use the code you showed:

```
my_ascii = my_uni_string.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

If that gave you an error, then you didn't really have a Unicode string to begin with.  If that is true, then you have a byte string instead.  You'll need to know what encoding it's using, and you can turn it into a Unicode string with:

```
my_uni_string = my_byte_string.decode('utf8')
```

(assuming your encoding is UTF-8).

This split between byte string and Unicode string can be confusing.  My presentation, [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop The Pain](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) can help you to keep it all straight.

Comment: Thanks you for the presentation. But I how do I find out the encoding of the original text?

Comment: @cheng I'm not sure you can just intuit the encoding of a random string easily. It's probably shown somewhere to you though, in the file or elsewhere

Comment: As is explained in the presentation, you have to know the encoding by some prior agreement.  You can guess the encoding, but the only way to know for sure is to have a spec that explains what the encoding is.

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect (especially for shorter strings) but the chardet library would be of use here:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet

To have chardet figure out the encoding and then encode as unicode you would do:

```
import chardet
encoding = chardet.detect(some_string)['encoding']
unicode_string = unicode(some_string, encoding)
```

Of course, you won't be able to encode them as ascii if they're out of the ascii range.